# Guardar cada elemento de una lista en variables independientes

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Tengo una lista de números ejemplo:

```
lista[10,20,30,40,50]
```

Esta lista varía de elementos cada día y quiero hacer que cada elemento de esa lista se guarde en una base de datos *sqlite3* de forma que luego pueda hacer operaciones con cada número, del tipo cuántas veces ha salido un mismo número, etc.

Lo hago a través de:

```
cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO  mi_tabla VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Pero no soy capaz de hacer que guarde cada elemento de la lista por separado. Ando un poco perdido, ¿me podríais orientar y ponerme en el camino?

```
url_page = 'https://www.loteriasyapuestas.es/es/resultados' # Url que queremos hacer web scraping
page = requests.get(url_page).text # pasamos el código ya convertido a texto dentro de una variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml") # le pasamos soup

fecha = soup.find('p', {'class':'c-ultimo-resultado__fecha'}) # Fecha del sorteo
fechasorteo = fecha.text # eliminamos todo el código menos el texto

euro_result = soup.find('ul', {'id':'qa_ultResult-combination-mainNumbers-EMIL'}) # numeros ganadores
euroresultado = [euro_result.text] # eliminamos código y metemos el resultado en una lista

euro_estrellas = soup.find('ul', {'class':'c-ultimo-resultado__estrellas-ul'}) # estrellas del sorteo
euroestrellas = [euro_estrellas.text] # eliminamos código y metemos el resultado en una lista


euroresultado = [words.split() for words in euroresultado] #dividimos cada número en un elemento de la lista
euroestrellas = [words.split() for words in euroestrellas] #dividimos cada estrella en un elemento de la lista


print("Fecha:", fechasorteo)
print("el resultado es:", euroresultado)
print("las estrellas son:", euroestrellas)

# Conexión con la base de datos
def sql_connection():
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
        return con
    except Error:
        print(Error)
def sql_table(con):
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute("CREATE TABLE euromillones(fecha text, numero1 text,numero2 text,numero3 text,numero4 text,numero5 text, estrella1 text,estrella2 text)")
    con.commit()
con = sql_connection()
sql_table(con)

def sql_insert(con):
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO euromillones VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (fechasorteo, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

sql_insert(con)
```

Comment: Que es lo que tienes hasta ahora ?¿¿?¿

Comment: Subo mi código, cualquier sugerencia para depurarlo y sanearlo es bienvenida.

Comment: creo que una solución seria iterar en la lista que tienes y en cada iteración agregar el valor en la BD

Answer (score 1):

Tengo la impresión que tenés 1 sorteo diario. En ese caso, cada renglón de tu base de datos debería tener la fecha del sorteo y un valor de tu lista.

Podría quedar así:

```html
def sql_insert(con):
    resultados = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    cursorObj = con.cursor()
    for resultado in resultados:
      cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO euromillones VALUES(?, ?)", (fechasorteo, resultado))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Recomendaría que los valores vayan por parámetro en la función, lo volvería más reutilizable. Pero tu pregunta es sobre como almacenarlo en la base de dato. Para obtener los resultaodos del sorteo haces un select con la fecha del sorteo como condición.

También podrías hacer uso de one-liners, pero elijo omitirlo porque me da la impresión que en este caso sería menos legible.